# Next and Previous Buttons with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having a problem getting next and previous buttons to work using a php webpage connected to mysql database.  I am not sure what is wrong but i think it may have something to do with the offset.  Right now the button are not working at all you click them and nothing happens.  Also the form is made as a search page.

Here is the search code:

```
<?php
     include("../web-admin/dbconfiginc.php");
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE ID = '$ID'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 ?><strong></strong>

<title>Search </title>

</head>

<body>

<table align="center" width="1024" border="0">

  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" width="70%" style="padding-top:10px;" class="lhc">


<div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
<?php 

$Keyword = $_POST['Keyword'];
$GuestName = $_POST['GuestName'];
$Day = $_POST['Day'];
$Month = $_POST['Month'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];

  if(isset($cancel))
  {
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
  }

  $qry_string = "SELECT * FROM videos "; 
  $search = "";

  if(!empty($Keyword))

  {
    $End_String = "(Blurb LIKE '%$Keyword%' OR Title LIKE '%$Keyword%')";
    $search .="&Keyword=$Keyword";
  }

  if(!empty($GuestName))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (GuestName LIKE '%$GuestName%')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(GuestName LIKE '%$GuestName%')";
     }
    $search .="&GuestName=$GuestName";
  }

  if(!empty($Day))
    {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (DAYOFMONTH(Publish_Date) = '$Day')";
    }
    else
   {
     $End_String = "(DAYOFMONTH(Publish_Date) = '$Day')";
    }
    $search .="&Day=$Day";
  }

  if(!empty($Month))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
  {
  $End_String .= " AND (MONTH(Publish_Date) = '$Month')";
   }
   else
   {
  $End_String = "(MONTH(Publish_Date) = '$Month')";
}
$search .="&Month=$Month";
  }

  if(!empty($Year))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
  {
   $End_String .= " AND (YEAR(Publish_Date) = '$Year')";
}
else
{
  $End_String = "(YEAR(Publish_Date) = '$Year')";
}
$search .="&Year=$Year";
}

  if(!empty($Active))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (GuestName LIKE '%$GuestName%')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(GuestName LIKE '%$GuestName%')";
    }
    $search .="&GuestName=$GuestName";
   }

   if (!isset($offset)) $offset=0;

  if(isset($End_String))
  {
    $qry_string = $qry_string." WHERE ".$End_String . "ORDER BY Publish_Date DESC LIMIT $offset, 101";
  }
  else
  {
    $qry_string = $qry_string."ORDER BY Publish_Date DESC LIMIT $offset, 101";
  }

  $result = mysql_query($qry_string);
  echo mysql_error();
?>
```

And here is the code that displays the results from the database

```
<?php
  $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

  if (!isset($search))
        $search = "";
?>

 <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>

 </td></tr></table>


  <table width="95%" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width=25%>
        <?php
          if ($offset > 99) {
            echo '<a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?$offset='.($offset-100).'>Previous 100</a>';
          } else {
            echo 'Previous 100';
          }
        ?>
      </td>
      <td align=center width=10%>
        <span class="content1"><a href=search.php>Search </a></span>
      </td>
      <td align=right width=25%>
      <?php
        if($num_records == 101) {
         echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?offset='.($offset+100) .$search.'">Next 100</a>';
        } else {
          echo 'Next 100';
        }
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#666666" style="margin: 5px 15px; 5px 10px;">
    <tr style="background: #9ae6f1; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 65%; padding: 5px;">
        Video
    </td>
      <td align="center" style="width: 10%; padding: 5px;">
        Guest Name
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="width: 10%; padding: 5px;">
        Date
      </td>
    </tr>

  <?php
  $count = 1;
    $bgc = 1;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

    if ($count > 100) break;
    echo '<tr style="background: ';
        if (($bgc == 0 ? $bgc=1 : $bgc=0) == 0) echo "#FFFFFF";
        else echo "#E6E6E6";

    echo ';">';
    echo '<td><div style="padding: 3px;" class="content"><a href=../../watch/watch.php?ID='.$row[ID].'>'.$row[Title].'</a></div></td>';
    echo '<td><div style="padding: 3px;"     class="content">'.$row[GuestName].'</div></td>';
    echo '<td><div align="center" style="padding: 3px;"     class="content">'.$row[Publish_Date].'</div></td></tr>';
    $count++;
  }
  ?>

  </table>

  <table width="95%" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#111111" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width=25%>
        <?php
          if($offset > 99) {

            echo '<span class="content"><a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?offset='.($offset-100).$search.'>Previous 100</a></span>';
          } else {
            echo 'Previous 100';
          }
        ?>
      </td>
      <td align=center width=10%>
        <span class="content1"><a href=search.php>Search </a></span>
      </td>
      <td align=right width=25%>
      <?php
        if($num_records == 101) {
          echo '<span class="content"><a href='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?offset='.($offset+100).$search.'>Next 100</a></span>';
        } else {
          echo 'Next 100';
        }
      ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Would really appreciate some help trying to figure this out or some points in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Hard to say. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to **all** your `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Plus, no idea where `$ID` and `$offset` are defined along with other variables I didn't go through that may not be defined. Use the above ^

Comment: Okay the error_reporting script you gave shot back a lot of stuff for me to check out.  Basically its kind of just repeating this `Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID' in /homepages/33/d533781759/htdocs/site/watch/display_search.inc on line 66`  But i think i defined the offset here in the first code group i put up, correct me if this is correct `if (!isset($offset)) $offset=0;`

Comment: It is displaying the results from the database it just isn't allowing to browse through the results using next and previous buttons.  I don't know if this is worth mentioning but if i modify the code of `if (!isset($offset)) $offset=0;` to `if (!isset($offset)) $offset=20;` for instance it will show another page of results pulled from the database

Comment: You do not seem to set offset: **$offset = $_GET['offset'];**. Also start reading up on SQL injection: Your code can be hacked real easy (10s tops).

Comment: Looks like the `offset = $_GET['offset'];` worked thank you so much!  And for the sql injection i will start reading up on that, as i do not want my code hacked!

Comment: @MeganTravis - You would spend your time well if you research PDO and prepared statements. PDO (Php Data Objects) allows you to use any one of a number of different database engines with little or no modification to the bulk of your code - it's often as simple as changing the connection string to work with MySQL, MsSQL, Oracle, SQLite, etc, etc. Using prepared statements means that your data is correctly escaped and allows you to bind a php variable to a sql variable - you dont directly manipulate the strings. They also alleviate the following problem: https://xkcd.com/327/